# Task 'afterEclipseImport' not found in root project 'NEWGDL'

Tags: libgdx, project, root

I'm trying to make a new project to work on in eclipse using libGDX. I managed to get a project working before, but after deleting some files the project became unusable.
Now when I try to use libGDX project setup I'm told "Task 'afterEclipseImport' not found in root project 'NEWGDL'." (NEWGDL being the selected workspace for the GDX projects)

And there are no projects to import into my eclipse workspace.
I'm only trying to build Android, and Box2d is checked.

Could someone please tell me what went wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Restore the files you deleted?

Comment: The files were just what I was working on in eclipse,, Mygame.java, Enemies.java, etc

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I reported the [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2134) and it was fixed 4 days ago, the error no longer shows up with the latest libGDX project setup app.